# spring state machine in multi threaded environment

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-statemachine

We have just started using spring state machine. Have a couple of questions:

- Is the state context only once per state machine?
- Do the events passed to the state machine run in a blocking way? Any way to make them run in parallel, like, providing a new state machine everytime an event is triggered?

Here is my code:

*Configuring the states and transitions:*

```
@Override
public void configure(
        StateMachineTransitionConfigurer<WorkFlowStates, WorkFlowEvent> transitions)
                throws Exception {
    transitions
    .withExternal()
    .source(WorkFlowStates.ready)
    .target(WorkFlowStates.l1Creation)
    .event(WorkFlowEvent.createWorkItem)
    .action(workFlowCreator.createL1())
```

*Providing actions during state transitions:*

```
public Action<WorkFlowStates, WorkFlowEvent> createL3() {
    return new Action<WorkFlowStates, WorkFlowEvent>() {

        public void execute(StateContext<WorkFlowStates, WorkFlowEvent> context) {
            System.out.println("l3 creation in action");
            Map<Object, Object> variables = context.getExtendedState().getVariables();
            Integer counter = (Integer)variables.get("counter");
            if(counter == null) counter = 1;
            else counter = counter+1;
            variables.put("counter", counter);
            System.out.println("Counter is "+counter);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            variables.put(Level.l3, WorkItemFactory.createFailureL1L2L3WorkItem());
            variables.put("level", Level.l3);
            System.out.println("l3 created");
        }
    };
}
```

Task executor:

```
public void configure(StateMachineConfigurationConfigurer<WorkFlowStates, 
WorkFlowEvent>config)
                throws Exception {
    config
    .withConfiguration()
    .autoStartup(true)
    .taskExecutor(taskExecutor())
    .listener(new WorkFlowStateMachineListener()); 
}

@Bean(name = StateMachineSystemConstants.TASK_EXECUTOR_BEAN_NAME)
public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    taskExecutor.afterPropertiesSet();
    taskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(5);
    return taskExecutor;
}
```

*And events passed to the state machine:*

```
StateMachine<WorkFlowStates, WorkFlowEvent> stateMachine = 
    context.getBean(StateMachine.class);

    stateMachine.sendEvent(WorkFlowEvent.createWorkItem);
    stateMachine.sendEvent(WorkFlowEvent.createWorkItem);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, default behaviour is blocking as underlying `TaskExecutor` is `SyncTaskExecutor`. This can be changed via [common config](http://docs.spring.io/spring-statemachine/docs/1.1.0.RC1/reference/htmlsingle/#statemachine-config-commonsettings) as mentioned in docs. Also see [tasks recipe](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-statemachine/blob/master/spring-statemachine-recipes/src/main/java/org/springframework/statemachine/recipes/tasks/TasksHandler.java#L235) where `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` is used on default to execute regions parallel.

When moving away from a blocking machine you need to pay attention how machine works and when its ready to process further events as machine may then be in a state where events are discarded. This is usually when you may need to start adding deferred events so that machine can process those in future in more suitable time.

Comment: Alright. Any views on the other question - "Is the state context only once per state machine?"

Comment: Ah yes, people usually mix what these contexts mean. `StateContext` is what's created per a transition and `StateMachineContext` is then more high level context which is usually used when persisting a machine. So not exactly "once per machine".

Comment: But the ThreadPoolTaskExecutor is useful only if we have tasks right?
When i ran it with just states, it is still blocking.

Comment: I think you need to show your code as that is a way to make state machine execution asynchronous. Probably what you did didn't replace default `SyncTaskExecutor`.

Comment: Sure. I have updated the code above with the task executor.

Comment: Ah, I need to check if that is a bug. `.taskExecutor(taskExecutor())` should override defaults. Could you leave it our and define bean as `@Bean(name = StateMachineSystemConstants.TASK_EXECUTOR_BEAN_NAME)`. Default bean name with annotation config used is `stateMachineTaskExecutor`, not `taskExecutor`.

Comment: Ya. So i changed the bean name to stateMachineTaskExecutor, but the same results.

Comment: Oh wait, I may have had a misunderstanding what you asked. Events in a single machine/region cannot ever be parallel as state machine is always run-to-completion by definition. Use of `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` will cause `sendEvent()` not to block for event processing. Parallel event execution can only happen if you have multiple independent orthogonal regions(which is what's used in tasks example).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Since, not all tasks can be parallelized, do you recommend creating multiple INSTANCES of a state machine?

Comment: If you can't represent your stuff in a single machine, then yes. That's why we have manual builders and @EnableStateMachineFactory.